# keyboard Shortcut to toggle between last edited and current working File on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

How can i **toggle (Swap)** between **last edited / used file** and **current working file** on Android Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> keys helped me to **toggle** between previous and current working files on Android studio.

You might see **switcher** window after you pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, just leave it and release the key the file will be toggled.

[image: Switcher window appears]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this tip